# Is it possible Kendo Grid return List<object>.ToDataSourceResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using default create button with a template. But according to inputs, multiple records are adding. Every thing works fine till return line. I m trying to return a list as data source result. But It gives an error like .

```
Unhandled exception at line 9, column 29037 in http://localhost:63882/Scripts/kendo/2013.3.716/kendo.all.min.js

JavaScript runtime error "0x800a03ec - expected ;"
```

Is it possible to return a list as DataSourceResult?

**Controller Grid Create Function**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult DonemKursSinifiOlustur([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int DonemId, string DersId, string EgitmenId, string Tanim, string dersSuresi, string baslangicSaati, string bitisSaati, string kontenjannsayisi, string TarifeId)
{
    List<DonemKursSinifi> models = new List<DonemKursSinifi>();
    model.Tanim = Tanim + " " + baslangicSaati + " - ";
    baslangicSaati = stringDateAddMinute(baslangicSaati, Convert.ToInt32(dersSuresi));
    model.Tanim += baslangicSaati;
    model = Helper.Islemci.DonemKursSinifiTanimla(model);
    models.Add(model);
    while (stringDateKarsilastir(baslangicSaati, bitisSaati) != 1)
    {
        model.Tanim = Tanim + " " + baslangicSaati + " - ";
        baslangicSaati = stringDateAddMinute(baslangicSaati, Convert.ToInt32(dersSuresi));
        model.Tanim += baslangicSaati;
        model = Helper.Islemci.DonemKursSinifiTanimla(model);
        models.Add(model);
    }
    return Json(new[] { models }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));//<=error here
}
```

**View Grid**

```
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Olgu.Kurs.Kurslar.Models.DonemKursSinifi>()
.Name("sinifGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    //Columns
    columns.Command(command =>
    {
        command.Edit().UpdateText("Güncelle").CancelText("İptal").Text("Güncelle").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:85" });
        command.Destroy().Text("Sil").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:55;padding 0 0 0 0;", @onclick = "Refresh()" });
    }).Width(190);
})
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:410px;width:auto;" })
.Pageable().Scrollable().AutoBind(false)
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
                  .Window(conf => conf.Title("Yeni Sınıf"))
                    .TemplateName("DonemKursSinifiTemplate")
                    .DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Seçili kaydı silmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?"))
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Sınıf Ekle").HtmlAttributes(new { @disabled = "disabled", id = "SinifEkleButton" }))
.Events(e => e.Edit("onEditSinif"))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Sort(s =>
        {
            s.Add(sinif => sinif.sortString).Ascending();
        }
    )
    .Read(read => read.Action("GridDonemKursSinifi", "Tanim").Data("data"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("DonemKursSinifiOlustur", "Tanim").Data("dataCreate"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("DonemKursSinifiGuncelle", "Tanim").Data("dataUpdate"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DonemKursSinifiSil", "Tanim"))

    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id)))
 .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true)))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
List<DonemKursSinifi> models = new List<DonemKursSinifi>();
model.Tanim = Tanim + " " + baslangicSaati + " - ";
baslangicSaati = stringDateAddMinute(baslangicSaati, Convert.ToInt32(dersSuresi));
model.Tanim += baslangicSaati;
model = Helper.Islemci.DonemKursSinifiTanimla(model);
models.Add(model);
while (stringDateKarsilastir(baslangicSaati, bitisSaati) != 1)
{
    model.Tanim = Tanim + " " + baslangicSaati + " - ";
    baslangicSaati = stringDateAddMinute(baslangicSaati, Convert.ToInt32(dersSuresi));
    model.Tanim += baslangicSaati;
    model = Helper.Islemci.DonemKursSinifiTanimla(model);
    models.Add(model);
}
DataSourceResult result = new DataSourceResult();
result.Data = models;
result.Total = models.Count;
return this.Json(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Rudresh. I've tried. It fix the error, grid showed only last added record. Maybe If we can add `request` to result, maybe it could work. But I don't know how it will be added :) Can you help me a bit more please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the result ToDataSourceResult like this:

```
        IQueryable<DonemKursSinifi> result = (IQueryable<DonemKursSinifi>)model.AsQueryable<DonemKursSinifi>();
        DataSourceResult results = result.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        results.Total = rows.Count;
        results.Data = rows;
        return Json(results, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public JsonResult DonemKursSinifiOlustur([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest,DonemKursSinifi model)
 {
      // Your Code some thing like this.....

     List<DonemKursSinifi > list = new List<DonemKursSinifi>();
      if (model!= null)
      {
       list .Add(model);
      }
     return Json(new DonemKursSinifi [] { model}.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest, ModelState));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.What is Category?

Comment: I think you mean  `return Json(new DonemKursSinifi[] { models }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));`,  I've tried this before and it says `Can not implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<DonemKursSinifi> to 'DonemKursSinifi'`